# Will my PCIe Card fit into my PCI Case

Tags: pci-express, pci, case

I was recently planning on some things to get for a PC I was going to build, I finished my list and made sure everything was compatible, and then, I was going through a final check, and then at the last item I was checking, this came along:

PCI Slots: 7

That appeared in my PC Case Specifications, I frantically searched the web to see if PCIe Expansion Cards (WLAN and High-End Sound in my case) would fit into my PCI Case. I never thought I'd run across this issue because PCI was overridden a long time ago! All I found were stupid advertisements telling me to get the 'cheaper, better than you have case!' At most, I found how to make PCI Cards fit in a PCIe Motherboard, which was a scam and was also useless (to me). At the end of the day, I really just need to know by 'PCI Slots: 7', it means any PCI or PCIe Card, or whatever, but I just need to know if my PCIe Cards will be compatible with this so called PCI Case.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Case manufactures are extremely lazy with their specifications in some cases.  Please provide the exact model number you are talking about so the proper amount of research can be put into an answer before submitting it.

Comment: Having had recently spend months shopping for a computer case, the manufactures typically just refer to the PCIe slots, as expansion slots.  Since PCIe is the only standard that would use an expansion slot on a case, that description, is more then adequate.

Comment: Which case are you shopping?

Answer (score 2):

While the technical specifications are not compatible and even the slot length is different, the outer measurments of the cards are basically the same. So yes, PCIe cards should fit into cases built for PCI cards, at least if you're using ATX mainboards and cases.